# Jquery Error validation insert div using after() but cannot remove

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show error validation messages next to the textbox. For that, I have used `after()` function and inserted a div. But the div gets appended again and again whenever the field is invalid. I just want it once. Can anybody help me with it?

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("#name").blur(function()
  {
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var txt= /^[A-Za-z\s]+$/i ;
    if((txt.test(name) != true))
    {
      $("#name").after('<div id="one" style="color:#00aaff;">Invalid Name</div>');
      $("#one").empty();
    }
    else
    {
      $("#one").remove();
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use HTML 5 field's validity which is the standard.

```
 <input type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+"
oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Your error message here')"
onchange="setCustomValidity('')" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use additional variable to store your state. Try this logic.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var flag = false;

    $("#name").blur(function() {
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var txt = /^[A-Za-z\s]+$/i;

        if (!txt.test(name) && !flag) {
            $("#name").after('<div id="one" style="color:#00aaff;">Invalid Name</div>');
            flag = true;
        }
        else if (flag && txt.test(name)) {
            flag = false
            $("#one").remove();
        }
    });
});
```